# Maven generates .war that doesn't work on my remote tomcat

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, nexus

On my local machine, when I clone the project from Gitlab and generate the .war file after downloading all the dependencies from Nexus, it works fine on my local Tomcat 8 server.

But when I do the same process on CentOS 7 remote virtual machine that does have the exactly same version of jdk and maven, the .war file is also correctly generated by “mvn deploy” but when I put the file into the webapp directory and run tomcat it catch an exception below:

> org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory cannot be cast to ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext

I added logback-access and logback-core.jar into the lib directory of tomcat.
I don’t think that there is an issue with the tomcat configuration or the logback.xml considering that when I put the .war file generated on my local machine into the remote tomcat, it works fine.

Jdk 1.8.0_271
Maven 3.6.3
Tomcat 8
Centos 7

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try comparing the contents of WEB-INF/lib directory of war generated on your local with war generated on remote server.It's possible that the war generated on remote server has a corrupted library. You might want to check the number of jars and their respective size.

Comment: Does the remote Tomcat run other wars too?

Comment: @Shailendra I compared between the two WEB-INF/lib, they have exactly the same number of jar but the have a slightly different sizes. I also discovered that when I download the .war file from the remote machine, and extract it on local with the command "jar -xvf" and regenrate the .war with "jar -cvf", It then works on the remote Tomcat.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I only run one war on Tomcat